# API REST Consultando outra API

Tags: api, asp.net-core, rest, asp.net-web-api

Preciso fazer uma API REST, que consultasse dados de uma API em nuvem, e retornasse no app em formato json, porém, mesmo com muita pesquisa, não achei nada parecido, eu só queria saber como eu poderia fazer para que a API REST que eu for criar acesse os dados que já estão nessa API na nuvem.

Ps: estou fazendo a API em .Net Core

Comment: Uma api "em .Net core" nada difere de outras aplicações para fazer pedidos http. Da uma olhada neste link (em inglês) com algumas informações importantes https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests

Answer (score 2):

Sua pergunta é meio vaga, mas vou exemplificar uma forma de fazer isso, no exemplo vou supor que você consegue se conectar e consumir essa API em nuvem já que não citou ter dúvidas nisso.

Resumidamente basta criar um método normalmente na sua API, e dentro desse método você faz a requisição na API desejada. Se tiver parâmetros passe aos parâmetros para sua API e depois utilize eles na chamada da API em Nuvem.

Você criaria um método como esse na sua API:

```
    private object GravarLogAPI(string mensagem)
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();
        try
        {
            var dados = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(mensagem);
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, this.strUrlEnderecoAPI);
            request.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/json");
            request.Content = new StringContent(
                dados.ToString(),
                Encoding.UTF8,
                "application/json"
            );
            var response = client.SendAsync(request).Result;
            var result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<object>(result);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            client.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Importante você trocar o this.strUrlEnderecoAPI pelo endereço da sua API em nuvem.
Importante também que nesse exemplo faço um post e recebo um resultado, você não disse qual método HTTP você precisa chamar, mas caso precise fazer um get é só trocar o post pelo GET.

Comment: Se tiver solucionado seu problema marque como solucionado por favor, se tiver dúvidas pode escrevê-las aqui.